# Polymer 2 computed binding with nested functions in dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I am using vaadin-grid to create a table dynamically (including the number of columns!) like this

```
<vaadin-grid id="grid" style="flex:1" items="[[tableData]]">  
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[tableColumns]]" as="column">
        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">                                  
                [[column.header]]                                                                                                           
           </template>
            <template>
                <!--[[formatNumberForTable(get(column.value, item))]]--> ***
                [[get(column.value, item)]]
            </template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
    </template>  
</vaadin-grid>
```

`tableColumns` gets filled at runtime and determines the number of columns and their headers. To dynamically determine which property of `item` to display in the individual columns, I was advised to use `get(column.value, item)` where `column.value` gets dynamically filled with the name of the according property. This works well.

The problem is that I also would like to format the value. But code like the line marked with *** does not work, it prints out the source code instead of the value.

How can I format my values?

Comment: This is not answering your question, but what I do is, I run my data through a formatter before assigning it to `tableData`.


`this.tableData= Object.keys(rawData).map((key) => ({
     value: key,
     name: this._camelCaseToString(key),
    }));`

Comment: I considered that too but the problem is that my formatting routine is supposed to round the floating point numbers or maybe restrict the numbers of decimals consistently. On the other side the same data should at any time be exportable as CSV files where I want to keep the initial precision. So, your suggestion should work but would force me to keep another (formatted) copy of my data. Maybe I should do some performance tests to see how big a problem that actually is.

Comment: I suggest let the back handle the creation of the CSV. So if you click the export to csv button. It is call to the backend to fetch the CSV.

Comment: It seems like preformatting the data in a separate array breaks the grids sorting function when my format has a different locale. For example, in many european countries the decimal separator is a comma. When I preformat the data the grid is not able to correctly sort numerically anymore. I can not presort the data either because I want to allow the user to change the sorting via vaading-grid-sorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have callback functions in your HTML code.

```
<!--[[formatNumberForTable(get(column.value, item))]]--> ***
```

Let `formatNumberForTable` instead call the `get` method inside itself.

```
[[formatNumberForTable(column.value, item)]]

formatNumberForTable: function(column.value, item) {
  var variable = this.get(column.value, item);

  // do something more with 'variable'

  return variable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar before with 'column' and 'item' as parameters and was confused by the fact that the second parameter came in undefined. So I was led to the assumption I couldn't have more than one parameter. Now, after testing again, it looks like this function is called for every change to every parameter individually. That means that on the first call 'item' is undefined, on the second call both 'column' and 'item' have valid values. By doing 'if(!item) return', I can ignore the first call.